# Python Sympy - Check if a variable is present in the monomials of the ANF of a Boolean expression

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, boolean-expression

I have a Boolean expression that is transformed to its Algebraic Normal Form (ANF), with the logic module of Sympy. We don't know in advance what is the degree of the monomials of the ANF: it could be 1, 2, 3, etc.
Find below a dummy example with six variables.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.logic.boolalg import to_anf

a = symbols('a:{}'.format(2))
b = symbols('b:{}'.format(3))
c = symbols('c:{}'.format(1))

expr = ((a[0] & (~b[0])) ^ b[1]) & ((a[1] & (~b[2])) ^ c[0])
anf  = expr.to_anf()
```

which prints

```
(a0 & a1) ^ (a0 & c0) ^ (a1 & b1) ^ (b1 & c0) ^ (a0 & a1 & b0) ^ (a0 & a1 & b2) ^ (a0 & b0 & c0) ^ (a1 & b1 & b2) ^ (a0 & a1 & b0 & b2)
```

For this example, the minimum degree of the monomials is 2 (i.e., two variables are multiplied).
I would like to find which monomials of the resulting ANF have one variable in particular (e.g., `c0` in the example above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

1. to first split the monomials of the ANF,

```
monomials = [monom for monom in anf.args if anf.args]
```

2. then check if the variable is present in each monomial.

```
[monom for monom in monomials if c[0] in monom.args]
```

Output:

```
[a0 & c0, b1 & c0, a0 & b0 & c0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a certain type of subexpression, using `atoms` can be a good way to go:

```py
# after your code
>>> from sympy import And
>>> [i for i in anf.atoms(And) if i.has(c[0])]
[b1 & c0, a0 & b0 & c0, a0 & c0]
```

Comment: Elegant! I didn't know about the ```.atoms()``` function.

Comment: This solution assumes that all the monomials have a ```And``` operator (single variables will not be 'catched').